# Sidebar help for Google Maps API V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I need help to create a sidebar. I have it partially working, but there are 2 problems to solve.  First, the sidebar only shows the last marker information.  I may not have placed some of the sidebar coding in its proper place.  Second, (which may be part of the first problem), all the icons appear when using Firefox, but when using IE8 all the icons except the last icon appears.   To view the map and code, first go to http://www.askdata.net/propmap/mapdata.php and do the demo (paste addresses into text area), then the map page will be displayed.  Thanks again.  The code also follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-    strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">

<h1>'Comparables Map'</h1><!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Comparables Map</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var customIcons = {
      Subject: {
    icon: 'http://askdata.net/compmap/mapicons/sub.png',
    //shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  },
      Comp1: {
    icon: 'http://askdata.net/compmap/mapicons/c1.png',
    //shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  },
  Comp2: {
    icon: 'http://askdata.net/compmap/mapicons/c2.png',
    //shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  },
  Comp3: {
    icon: 'http://askdata.net/compmap/mapicons/c3.png',
    //shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  },
  Comp4: {
    icon: 'http://askdata.net/compmap/mapicons/c4.png',
    //shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  },
  Comp5: {
    icon: 'http://askdata.net/compmap/mapicons/c5.png',
    //shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  },
  Comp6: {
    icon: 'http://askdata.net/compmap/mapicons/c6.png',
    //shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  } 
   };

function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.95, -87.65),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'

  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;



  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("genxml2.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + type + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        draggable: true,
        icon: icon.icon
        //shadow: icon.shadow
      });




      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);


       var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
   sidebar.innerHTML = '';
   if (markers.length == 0) {
     sidebar.innerHTML = 'No results found.';
     map.setCenter(new GLatLng(41, -87), 4);
     return;
   }

     var sidebarEntry = createSidebarEntry(marker, type, address);
     sidebar.appendChild(sidebarEntry);




    }
  });

  function createSidebarEntry(marker, type, address) {


  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var html = '<b>' + type + '</b>' + address;
  div.innerHTML = html;
  div.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  div.style.marginBottom = '5px'; 
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, 'click', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, 'mouseover', function() {
    div.style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, 'mouseout', function() {
    div.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  });
  return div;
}


}



function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);



}

function doNothing() {}

//]]>

</script>

</head>

<body onload="load()">

<br/>    
<br/>
<div style="width:1200px; font-family:Arial, 
sans-serif; font-size:11px; border:1px solid black">
<table> 
<tbody> 
  <tr id="cm_mapTR">

    <td width="200" valign="top"> <div id="sidebar" style="overflow: auto; height: 700px;     font-size: 11px; color: #000"></div>

    </td>
    <td> <div id="map" style="overflow: hidden; width: 1000px; height: 700px"></div> </td>

  </tr> 
  </tbody>
  </table>

  </div>    


  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Got further, but still need help.  There are 2 problems to solve.  First, the sidebar only shows the last marker information.  I may not have placed some of the sidebar coding in its proper place.  Second, (which may be part of the first problem), all the icons appear when using Firefox, but when using IE8 all the icons except the last icon appears.   To view the map and code, first go to http://www.askdata.net/propmap/mapdata.php and do the demo (paste addresses into text area), then the map page will be displayed.  Thanks in advance for any help.  Gary.

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't like trailing commas at the end of a structure, e.g. the comma after the icon here:

```
Comp5: {
    icon: 'http://askdata.net/compmap/mapicons/c5.png',
  }
```

You're mixing Google Maps API 2 and 3 code.  e.g. you declare latlng objects using API 3:

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.95, -87.65)
```

but then you use API 2 here:

```
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(41, -87), 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem: **`sidebar.innerHTML = '';`**

Since it is within the loop, every time it loops, it deletes the prior side bar entry.

- Place it fight after `function load() {` -Outside the loop AND within `Load()`.
- Use  `document.getElementById('sidebar').innerHTML = '';`
- Also, you have to do something about your `customIcons`
  You can change them to something like this

  `Subject: { icon: 'http://askdata.net/compmap/mapicons/sub.png' }`

And you are done!

**EXAMPLE**

```
function load() {
  document.getElementById('sidebar').innerHTML = '';
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
//rest of the code goes here
```

Also, it might be a good idea to replace this code with CSS:

```
div.style.cursor = 'pointer';
div.style.marginBottom = '5px'; 
google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, 'mouseover', function() {
    div.style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
});
google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, 'mouseout', function() {
    div.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
});
```

**CSS option:**

```
#sidebar {
    background-color: white;
}
#sidebar div {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 5px; 
}
#sidebar div:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```